# Fetch equivalent to jquery's $(document).ajaxError()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fetch-api

Is there a way to hook into all of the fetch API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) ajax call errors similar to jquery's $(document).ajaxError()?

We're using $(document).ajaxError() to detect Session Timeout/failures and present a Login dialog. I would like to detect timeouts as soon as I get a failed response.

Here's some code:

```
    $(document).ajaxError((event, jqxhr) => {
        if (jqxhr.statusText === 'abort') {
            return;
        }


        // Sometimes (even with /restapi/session), we get no jqxhr.responseJSON, but we do have jqxhr.responseText
        let responseJSON = jqxhr.responseJSON;
        if (!responseJSON && jqxhr.responseText) {
            responseJSON = JSON.parse(jqxhr.responseText);
        }
        if (jqxhr.status === 401) {
            if (!responseJSON) {
                // https://sentry.zetta.net//zetta/prod-frontend/group/13631/
                alert('API call\'s responseJSON is empty, and so is jqxhr.responseText. Check the Console logs for more info.');
                console.error('jqxhr:', jqxhr, 'event:', event);
            }

            if (responseJSON.code === 1900) { // session expired
                this.setState({ showExpirationModal: true });
            } else {
                // TODO: consider removing handling of these errors locally
                // Currently we'd be showing 2 popups in some places: one with a "permission denied", and another with this error handler
                // alert('Unauthorized');
            }
        } else if (jqxhr.status === 500) { // TODO: see if we should to all 500 errors in this global handler
            if (responseJSON.code === 8017) { // maintenance mode
                alert(responseJSON.message);
            }
        } else if (!navigator.onLine) {
            this.setState({ showConnectionModal: true });
        } else if (responseJSON === undefined) {
            console.error(event, jqxhr);
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure if the Fetch API supports this.

Comment: you could try `$.ajaxSetup`

Comment: Please be a lot more specific. See [ask] ... and ... [mcve]

Comment: No, there is no global ajax error handler (and that for good reason)

Comment: So, what you're saying is that the *real* question is how do I detect and handle timeouts with fetch? Why include all of this assorted brick-a-brac and rambling about jquery instead of just asking that?

Answer (score 0):

From the document linked at OP

> Note that the `fetch` specification differs from `jQuery.ajax()` in
>   mainly two ways that bear keeping in mind:
>
> - The `Promise` returned from `fetch()` **won’t reject on HTTP error status** even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will
>     resolve normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only
>     reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from
>     completing.

To get the status code, return [`Response.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status)

```
fetch("/path/to/server"/*, options object*/)
.then(response => ({headers: response.headers, code: response.status}))
.then(({headers, code}) => {
  for (let [key, value] of headers) {
    console.log(key, value)
  }
  console.log(code); // `403` at linked jsfiddle
  // if (code === /* code */) 
  // do stuff
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wgwd9hk3/

Comment: To get `Response.status`, `Response.headers` and response as `JSON`, text, `Blob` or `ArrayBuffer` https://jsfiddle.net/wgwd9hk3/1/